# In-App billing without having account at Google play developer console

Tags: android, in-app-billing

Is it possible to implement the In-App billing in an application just for testing without having Google play developer console account?

I am reffering this link to implement the In-App billing.
[In-App billing demo](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Integrating_Google_Play_In-app_Billing_into_an_Android_Application_%E2%80%93_A_Tutorial#Installing_the_Google_Play_Billing_Library)

I do not have my account on play store.So is it possible to implement it?If yes then please share me the link or way how can i do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You not just require a Google Developer Console for in-app purchases but you also need to have a merchant account linked and then you would be able to do that. Other than that if you want to test it. you can do it **[from here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html)** without all this.

But for a proper pucrhase you need to have both merchant account and a developer console

Comment: Thanks NSQuamber for your kind information.Let me check the link you have provided .

Comment: Welcome @DeepakSharma. Also that in the need you should focus on Topic "Testing with Static Responses"